# How to use sed to print the match patten

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

i want to use sed to print the match patten, for example:
i want to get the uuid , so i can use this :
`blkid $1 | grep -o -E "[a-f0-9-]{8}([a-f0-9-]{4}){3}[a-f0-9-]{12}"`
How can i do this use sed or awk ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want this?

awk:

```
kent$  echo '/dev/sda6: UUID="c6e3ce88-f44e-4261-9178-042db8423081" TYPE="ext3"'|awk -F'UUID="|" ' '{print $2}'
c6e3ce88-f44e-4261-9178-042db8423081
```

sed:

```
kent$  echo '/dev/sda6: UUID="c6e3ce88-f44e-4261-9178-042db8423081" TYPE="ext3"'|sed -r 's/.*UUID="([^"]*).*"/\1/g'
c6e3ce88-f44e-4261-9178-042db8423081
```

Answer (score 4):

`sed`

```
sed -n 's/pattern/&/p' file
```

`-n` is to tell `sed` to be quiet, `&` is matched string, `p` is to print.

`awk`

```
awk '/pattern/' file
```

in your case, change `pattern` to `[a-f0-9-]{8}([a-f0-9-]{4}){3}[a-f0-9-]{12}`, may need to use `\` to escape `[`.

Comment: pattern is wrong. The right one: [a-f0-9-]{8}-([a-f0-9-]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9-]{12}

Comment: `sed -n '/pattern/p'` does the job - it does a "print" instead of a "replace-with-self and-print"

Answer (score 1):

```
blkid | sed -nr 's/^.+UUID="(.*?)" .+$/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk and sed solutions:

```
$ blkid /dev/sda2 | sed -e 's/.*UUID="\([0-9A-F]*\).*/\1/'
16A42BA2A42B837B

$ blkid /dev/sda2 | awk '{split($2, tmp, "=") ; print tmp[2]}'
"16A42BA2A42B837B"

$ blkid /dev/sda2 | awk -F'UUID="|"' '{print $2}'
16A42BA2A42B837B
```

Answer (score 0):

use sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(Pattern\).*/\1/p'
```

tested

> echo "< TextValue > Start < /TextValue >"
>       < TextValue > Start < /TextValue >
>   echo "< TextValue > Start < /TextValue >" | sed -n 's/.*(Start).*/\1/p'
>       Start

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice list of `sed` one-liners at http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt.  It suggests two methods of emulating `grep`:

```
sed -n '/regexp/p'           # method 1
sed '/regexp/!d'             # method 2
```

`/regexp/p` prints the lines matching `/regexp/`.  (The `-n` flag is needed to prevent `sed` from printing/reprinting every processed line.)

`/regexp/!d` deletes every line that *doesn't* match `/regexp/`, so only the matching lines are printed.